# Can't get user online on Openfire through WebSockets and strophe-openfire.js

Tags: websocket, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am trying to make real-time chat using HTML5, WebSockets, strophe-openfire.js library (https://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/source/browse/trunk/src/ofchat/js/strophejs/src/strophe-openfire.js) and Openfire server.
I use this code snippet to make connection:

```
function connectHandler(cond) {  
    log("connected");  
    connection.send($pres());  
}

var url = "ws://localhost:7070/ws";    
connectButton.onclick = function() {  
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;  
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;  
    var connection = new Openfire.Connection (url);  
   connection.connect(username, password,  connectHandler);  
}
```

I see on Openfire admin console in Client Sessions tab that user is "Authenticated" but is still Offline. On Chrome console I see response from Openfire with **101 Switching Protocols** and appropriate headers but nothing more.

so my question is what can be the cause that `connection.send($pres())` doesn't work and how to send presence to Openfire.

thanks in advance.
Andrew

Comment: CLOSED: found workaround in using openfire-websockets.js and peek.js library shipped with Openfire Websockets plugin. Sending presence through raw XML send.

Comment: can you tell me how did you install websocket plugin for openfire ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't help with an answer, but I am having the exact same problem. My Openfire server establishes the websocket connection, but never returns a response for:

`<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream to='satellite-l675' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'  xml:lang='en' xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">`

I am using Openfire 3.8.2 with the .0006 websocktet plugin. I am trying to use Candy chat as the client.

I did by accident get it to communicate with the Openfire websocket by bypassing authentication and sending this:

Sent:
`<stream:stream to='satellite-l675' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'/>`

Sent:
`<presence xmlns='jabber:client'/>`

Sent:
`<iq type='get' from='@satellite-l675/Candy' to='welcome@conference.satellite-l675' id='disco3' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>`

Sent:
`<presence from='satellite-l675/Candy' to='welcome@conference.satellite-l675/yogi' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>`

Sent:
`<iq type='get' from='@satellite-l675/Candy' id='get1' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
        <list name='ignore'/>
    </query>
</iq>`

RECV:
`<body rid='3282533506' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <presence xmlns='jabber:client' from='welcome@conference.satellite-l675/yogi' to='msos_ws_candy@satellite-l675/MSOS_ws_Candy'>
        <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
            <item affiliation='none' role='participant'/>
        </x>
    </presence>
</body>`

So the websocket works but it isn't easy to understand why and how. And the interesting thing is, the SparkWeb demo included with Openfire works fine, but only sends `<iq>`'s. It doesn't even seem to bother with `<stream:...this...>` and `<stream:...that...>` stuff.

So, given limited documentation, I can only conclude that Openfire Websockets only use `<iq>`'s and my only successful communication was due the the `<iq>` sent requesting disco#info.

So how do we send a request for authentication? Any reference to good examples or documentation would be greatly appreciated.